# Parse a svg related string with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, svg, python-re

I would like to parse the **d attribute commands within a path element of a svg**. And I would like to do it in an efficient way. Therefore I decided to go with a regex function to avoid using several loops.

**What I want to achieve is to put the command letter along with its numeric values in a tuple and store all those tuples in a list e.g.** `[('M', '3', '18'), ('h', '10'), ...]`

Depending on the command letter there can be one to six numeric values following. These numeric value can have a dot ('.45') or a minus ('-3') or both in it ('-.55'). And there are not always spaces seperating them. e.g. `'c -.55.45 0 1 '`.

**My Approach:**

Here is what I tried so far. I tried to separate them with the re.findall method. But after that I had to group them with an additional loop and those connected numeric values with dots are still connected. Furthermore I would like to integrate the replace method into the findall patterns.

```
# Just an extract of a d command
d = 'M20 3H4c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v6c0 .55.45 1 1 1h16'   
commands = re.findall("[mMzZlLhHvVcCsSqGtTaA]|[0-99\-.]+", d.replace("-", " -"))

#output: ['M', '20', '3', 'H', '4', 'c', '-.55', '0', '-1', '.45', '-1', '1', 'v', '6', 'c', '0', '.55.45', '1', '1', '1', 'h', '16']

#goal: [('M', '20', '3'), ('H', '4'), ('c', '-.55', '0', '-1', '.45', '-1', '1'), ('v', '6'), ('c', '0', '.55', '.45', '1', '1', '1'), ('h', '16')]
```

Those dotted connected numeric values seems to be easy. I just separate them on the dots. But this is not possible because I could have a value like '1.55'. But then this value is separated with a space to the other value ('.55 1.45'). As I had a hard time with those regex patterns, it would be awesome if someone has a solution or at least could guide me into the right direction.

If I missed something or you need more information, just tell me and I will provide them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If there can be one to six arguments, the best you can do with a one-regex approach is to use `re.findall("([mMzZlLhHvVcCsSqGtTaA])\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+)(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?", d)`. But you will end up with empty items for missing arguments. See https://ideone.com/MrA8UQ. And you won't be able to get rid of them with that single regex, you will need to post-process with another list comprehension.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks!. This helps me a lot. I post process the list with a filter to get rid of those empty strings. But if I parse `M0 0h24v24H0z` this for example, the z gets lost. How do I have to modify the patterns?

Comment: That is because all your arguments seem to be optional, I thought there must be at least 1, you said there can be one to six. So, use https://ideone.com/lWDjW4

Comment: z and Z have no arguments. Commands that take arguments can generally have arguments repeated so M can have an infinite number of pairs of arguments following it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you've considered how complicated paths are e.g. a9.62 9.62 0 110-.05 is an arc with **6** values. 110-.05 there is actually 1 1 0 -0.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be only zero to six arguments, the best you can do with a one-regex approach is to use

```
re.findall("([mMzZlLhHvVcCsSqGtTaA])(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?", d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2fGwJ6/1). The `(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?` pattern is repeated 6 times to match 1 to 6 arguments and capture each of them into its own group. `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group, `\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+)` matches 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`), `(-?\d*\.?\d+)` captures into a group an optional `-` (`-?`), 0+ digits (`\d*`), an optional dot (`\.?`) and 1+ digits (`\d+`).

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3cBSri):

```
import re
d = 'M0 0h24v24H0z'   
commands = re.findall(r"([mMzZlLhHvVcCsSqGtTaA])(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(?:\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+))?", d)
print([tuple(list(filter(None, x))) for x in commands])
# => [('M', '0', '0'), ('h', '24'), ('v', '24'), ('H', '0'), ('z',)]
```